# How to apply integer cut to a simple MILP?

Tags: optimization, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming, relaxations

I'm self-studying on cutting plane methods, and I'm reviewing the following problem from Bertsimas' book (see below).  I know what cutting plane methods do, and how they eliminate infeasible solutions from the relaxed problem.  But, I can think of several examples where a solution to the relaxed problem will not be eliminated by the cut proposed in this example.

Here's the problem description, and then I'll explain a few examples where I believe the proposed integer cut will not solutions to the LP relaxation (equation 11.2 below):

[image: Example]
[image: 11-1]
[image: 11-2]

If $x^* = [0.5,0]$, for example, then I understand how the proposed integer cut $\sum_{j \in N} x_j \ge 1$ will eliminate such a solution. (This also applies for any other basic feasible solution that has 2 components whose first fractional component is less than $1$, and the other is 0).  However, the integer cut will not eliminate the following solution:  $x^*=[1.5,0]$, or for a problem of a different dimension, $x^*=[0.5,0.7,0]$, yet this is also has "at least one fractional basic variable."

How does such a cut eliminate these solutions?

Comment: Bertsimas has written more than one book. To which do you refer?

Comment: bertsimas and tsitsiklis introduction to linear optimization

Answer (score 1):

Note that the index of summation in the cut runs only over the nonbasic variables. So if $x^* = [1.5, 0],$ then $x^*_1$ is basic, $x^*_2$ is nonbasic, $N=\lbrace 2 \rbrace$ and the proposed cut is $x_2 \ge 1,$ which does in fact cut off $x^*.$